# django related objects filtering with cusom manager

Tags: django

I write custom manager for using it in template for showing related pics at side panel.
My manager work wrong and i cant understand why.

```
class RelatedPicsManager(models.Manager):
    use_for_related_fields = True

    def sidepics(self):
        return super(RelatedPicsManager, self).get_queryset().filter(side = True)

class News (models.Model):
    ...
    pass

class ExtPhoto(models.Model):
    news = models.ForeignKey(News, related_name = 'extphotos')
    side = models.BooleanField(...)
    ...
    objects = RelatedPicsManager()
```

When i get the news and try look all its side pics

```
>>> onnews.extphotos.sidepics()
```

my manager return all ExtPhoto objects with side = True. 
But i need only related with the "onenews".

Comment: You can't do that. The context is lost in your manager. You'd better use onenews.objects.side_extphotos() instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can solve this by using a custom `QuerySet`:

```
class ExtPhotoQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    def sidepics(self):
        return self.filter(side=True)

class ExtPhotoManager(models.Manager):
    use_for_related_fields = True

    def get_queryset(self):
        return ExtPhotoQuerySet(self.model)

class ExtPhoto(models.Model):
    objects = ExtPhotoManager()
```

That way, `onnews.extphotos.sidepics()` only filters the photos relating to `onnews`. If you also want to use `ExtPhoto.objects.sidepics()`, I suggest inheriting from `PassThroughManager` from [django-model-utils](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-model-utils/). This makes all queryset methods available on your manager.

Comment: Thank you! It works with a little fix. `onnews.extphotos.sidepics()` drops error `'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'sidepics'`, because we add method in the queryset, not in manager. That's why i need to call `onnews.extphotos.all().sidepics()` and it's not such elegant like calling the manager itself. But this is better than nothing.

Comment: Ah, right, `extphotos` is a manager, too. Using `PassThroughManager` should bypass that annoyance, as it makes `.sidepics()` available on your manager. See http://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/managers.html#passthroughmanager